# How do I remove the link element from the current page in a wp_list_pages menu?

Tags: menus

WP makes a list of links, and helpfully applies a current_page class, but I'm concerned with the accessibility issues of a link to the page you're on.

Normally I'd swap the `<a href` etc with a `<span`, How would you approach that with WordPress?

(apart from manually creating the list of pages!)

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible - usually I use the current page class to change the mouse hover and style to make it look unlinked. I wasn't aware there were accessibility issues with this - can you explain in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @McGirl Screen reader users are irritated by links to the current page. You cannot fix that with CSS.

Comment: Good to know! I hadn't considered how screen reader users would feel about links to the current page. I know it can't be fixed via CSS :) Thanks for the question - I'm going to look into implementing the solution on my sites too.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the entire walker class is a big pain... much more work than is justified for the result. But you can use a bit of javascript to remove the link. If you're including jquery, something like this should work:

```
jquery(document).ready(function() {
    jquery('.current_page_item a').removeAttr( 'href' );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just recently I published a plugin, that does exactly this: [Remove Redundant Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-redundant-links/). You may costumize the output per filter, examples are in the readme.